# Seaborn boxplot with 2 y-axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

How can I create a seaborn boxplot with 2 y-axes? I need this because of different scales. My current code will overwrite the first box in the boxplot, eg. it is populated by 2 first data item from first ax and first item from second ax.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.Series(np.random.uniform(0,1,size=10)),
                   'B': pd.Series(np.random.uniform(10,20,size=10)),
                   'C': pd.Series(np.random.uniform(10,20,size=10))})

fig = plt.figure()
# 2/3 of  A4
fig.set_size_inches(7.8, 5.51)

plt.ylim(0.0, 1.1)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1 = sns.boxplot(ax=ax1, data=df[['A']])

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

boxplot = sns.boxplot(ax=ax2, data=df[['B','C']])

fig = boxplot.get_figure()
fig
```

[image]

How do I prevent the first item getting overwritten?

EDIT:

If I add positions argument

```
boxplot = sns.boxplot(ax=ax2, data=df[['B','C']], positions=[2,3])
```

I get an exception:

```
TypeError: boxplot() got multiple values for keyword argument 'positions'
```

Probably because seaborn already sets that argument internally.

Comment: You want plot `A` on left then `B` then `C` on right side. Is than what you want ?

Comment: Exactly. FYI I just added an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may not make too much sense to use seaborn here. Using usual matplotlib boxplots allows you to use the `positions` argument as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.Series(np.random.uniform(0,1,size=10)),
                   'B': pd.Series(np.random.uniform(10,20,size=10)),
                   'C': pd.Series(np.random.uniform(10,20,size=10))})

fig, ax1  = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.8, 5.51))

props = dict(widths=0.7,patch_artist=True, medianprops=dict(color="gold"))
box1=ax1.boxplot(df['A'].values, positions=[0], **props)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
box2=ax2.boxplot(df[['B','C']].values,positions=[1,2], **props)

ax1.set_xlim(-0.5,2.5)
ax1.set_xticks(range(len(df.columns)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(df.columns)

for b in box1["boxes"]+box2["boxes"]:
    b.set_facecolor(next(ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler)["color"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: can you pass `positions` to `seaborn.boxplot`?

Comment: @PaulH Well, no. This results in `TypeError: boxplot() got multiple values for keyword argument 'positions'` according to the question.

Comment: @PaulH The reason is indeed that it is [hardcoded in the seaborn code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/0beede57152ce80ce1d4ef5d0c0f1cb61d118375/seaborn/categorical.py#L479).