# Grouped boxplot with 2 y axes 2 variables per x tick

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I am trying to make a boxplot of cost (in Rupees unit) and installed capacity (in Megawatt unit) with `xaxis` as share of renewables (in % unit).

That is each x tick is associated with two boxplots, one is the cost and one of the installed capacity. I have 3 xtick values `(20%, 40%, 60%)`.

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314094/grouped-boxplot-with-2-y-axes-2-plotted-variables-per-x-tick) but I get error that is attached on the bottom.

I need two boxplots per `xtick`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"
plt.style.use('seaborn-ticks')
plt.grid(color='w', linestyle='solid')
data1 = pd.read_csv('RES_cap.csv')
df=pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['per','cap','cost'])

cost= df['cost']
cap=df['cap']
per_res=df['per']

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
xticklabels = 3

ax1.set_xlabel('Percentage of RES integration')
ax1.set_ylabel('Production Capacity (MW)')
res1 = ax1.boxplot(cost, widths=0.4,patch_artist=True)
for element in ['boxes', 'whiskers', 'fliers', 'means', 'medians', 'caps']:
    plt.setp(res1[element])

for patch in res1['boxes']:
    patch.set_facecolor('tab:blue')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis
ax2.set_ylabel('Costs', color='tab:orange')
res2 = ax2.boxplot(cap, widths=0.4,patch_artist=True)
for element in ['boxes', 'whiskers', 'fliers', 'means', 'medians', 'caps']:
    plt.setp(res2[element], color='k')
for patch in res2['boxes']:
    patch.set_facecolor('tab:orange')

ax1.set_xticklabels(['20%','40%','60%'])
fig.tight_layout()  
plt.show()
```

[image: the output image is attached here]

sample data:
[data attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlqFS.png)

Comment: you can use `ax.set_ylim()` and `ax.set_yticks()` to align the ticks of both axes

Comment: What is the error? We don't have your data, so maybe this is the expected graph. How would we know?

Comment: Please don't post data/code/error messages as images. You are asking strangers on the internet for help. Do you really expect them to type your data from an image? Apart from that - an image does not contain the data type. Certain functions treat str(2), float(2), and int(2) totally different but may look identical in an image.

Comment: First of all, welcome to SO. As explained in [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you should help us reproduce your problem by [creating an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can easily use, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples?noredirect=1&lq=1) are some tips on how to do this. But I understand the trouble you are having, as I see that you have jumped straight into the deep end of plotting in Python. So I have posted an answer below with fake data, hope it helps.

Comment: I apologize for posting the question with the data as image and also not being very precise as to what error I was getting. I should have been through https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By testing your code and comparing it to the [answer by Thomas Kühn in the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314094/grouped-boxplot-with-2-y-axes-2-plotted-variables-per-x-tick), I see several things that stand out:

- the data you input for the `x` parameter has a 1-D shape instead of 2-D. You input one variable so you get one box instead of the three you actually want;
- the `positions` argument has not been defined, which causes the boxes of both boxplots to overlap;
- in the first `for` loop over `res1`, the `color` argument in `plt.setp` is missing;
- you have set x tick labels without first setting the x ticks (as cautioned [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html)) which causes an error message.

I offer the following solution which is based more on [this answer by ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47139863/14148248). It solves the issue of shaping the data correctly and it makes use of dictionaries to define many of the parameters that are shared by multiple objects in the plot. This makes it easier to adjust the format to your taste and also makes the code cleaner as it avoids the need for the `for` loops (over the boxplot elements and the `res` objects) and the repetition of arguments in functions that share the same parameters.

```
import numpy as np                 # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd                # v 1.1.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # v 3.3.2

# Create a random dataset similar to the one in the image you shared
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=123) # random number generator
data = dict(per = np.repeat([20, 40, 60], [60, 30, 10]),
            cap = rng.choice([70, 90, 220, 240, 320, 330, 340, 360, 410], size=100),
            cost = rng.integers(low=2050, high=2250, size=100))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Pivot table according to the 'per' categories so that the cap and
# cost variables are grouped by them:
df_pivot = df.pivot(columns=['per'])

# Create a list of the cap and cost grouped variables to be plotted 
# in each (twinned) boxplot: note that the NaN values must be removed
# for the plotting function to work.
cap = [df_pivot['cap'][var].dropna() for var in df_pivot['cap']]
cost = [df_pivot['cost'][var].dropna() for var in df_pivot['cost']]

# Create figure and dictionary containing boxplot parameters that are
# common to both boxplots (according to my style preferences):
# note that I define the whis parameter so that values below the 5th
# percentile and above the 95th percentile are shown as outliers
nb_groups = df['per'].nunique()
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6))
box_param = dict(whis=(5, 95), widths=0.2, patch_artist=True,
                 flierprops=dict(marker='.', markeredgecolor='black',
                 fillstyle=None), medianprops=dict(color='black'))

# Create boxplots for 'cap' variable: note the double asterisk used
# to unpack the dictionary of boxplot parameters
space = 0.15
ax1.boxplot(cap, positions=np.arange(nb_groups)-space,
            boxprops=dict(facecolor='tab:blue'), **box_param)

# Create boxplots for 'cost' variable on twin Axes
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.boxplot(cost, positions=np.arange(nb_groups)+space,
            boxprops=dict(facecolor='tab:orange'), **box_param)

# Format x ticks
labelsize = 12
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(nb_groups))
ax1.set_xticklabels([f'{label}%' for label in df['per'].unique()])
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=labelsize)

# Format y ticks
yticks_fmt = dict(axis='y', labelsize=labelsize)
ax1.tick_params(colors='tab:blue', **yticks_fmt)
ax2.tick_params(colors='tab:orange', **yticks_fmt)

# Format axes labels
label_fmt = dict(size=12, labelpad=15)
ax1.set_xlabel('Percentage of RES integration', **label_fmt)
ax1.set_ylabel('Production Capacity (MW)', color='tab:blue', **label_fmt)
ax2.set_ylabel('Costs (Rupees)', color='tab:orange', **label_fmt)

plt.show()
```

[image: boxplots_grouped_twinx]

Matplotlib documentation: [boxplot demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/boxplot_demo_pyplot.html), [boxplot function parameters](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html), [marker symbols for fliers](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html), [label text formatting parameters](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)

Considering that it is quite an effort to set this up, if I were to do this for myself, I would go for side-by-side subplots instead of creating twinned Axes. This can be done quite easily in seaborn using the [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) function which takes care of a lot of the formatting automatically. Seeing as there are only three categories per variable, it is relatively easy to compare the boxplots side-by-side using a different color for each percentage category, as illustrated with this example based on the same data:

```
import seaborn as sns    # v 0.11.0

# Convert dataframe to long format with 'per' set aside as a grouping variable
df_melt = df.melt(id_vars='per')

# Create side-by-side boxplots of each variable: note that the boxes
# are colored by default
g = sns.catplot(kind='box', data=df_melt, x='per', y='value', col='variable',
                height=4, palette='Blues', sharey=False, saturation=1,
                width=0.3, fliersize=2, linewidth=1, whis=(5, 95))

g.fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4)
g.set_titles(col_template='{col_name}', size=12, pad=20)

# Format Axes labels
label_fmt = dict(size=10, labelpad=10)
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.set_xlabel('Percentage of RES integration', **label_fmt)
g.axes.flatten()[0].set_ylabel('Production Capacity (MW)', **label_fmt)
g.axes.flatten()[1].set_ylabel('Costs (Rupees)', **label_fmt)

plt.show()
```

[image: boxplots_sbs]

Comment: Thank you for both the solutions. Also for explaining every step so thoroughly. Apologies for posting the data as image. Thank you for solving in spite of that.